# How do I remove hair from the face of this model?

Tags: particles, hair

[image: Blender beginner here. I would like to remove the hair from the face, nothing else, of this model.]

Blender beginner here. I would like to remove the hair from the face, nothing else, of this model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Weight Paint* mode, paint the face in order to create a vertex group:

[image]

Then in the *Particle* panel, under *Vertex Groups > Density*, select the vertex group, and invert the selection with the <-> button, also maybe select the vertex group under *Length*, now the face has no more hair:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much brother.